# how to upgrade jetpack on jetson tx2

Tags: nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetpack-sdk

I'm using Jetson TX2.

Current jetpack version : 4.5-b129

I was following update tutorial from nvidia website (https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/jetpack/install-jetpack/index.html).

I did:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install --fix-broken -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"
```

Last command feedback:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  activity-log-manager libgeonames-common libgeonames0
  libnm-gtk0 libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1
  libunity-control-center1 vulkan-utils
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I'm using `sudo apt-cache show nvidia-jetpack` to check jetpack version and it's still the same (4.5-b129)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there was note, that I thought is only for 5.0.X users:

> To upgrade from JetPack 5.0/5.0.1 Developer Preview, first edit etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-l4t-apt-source.list

I edited nvidia-l4t-apt-source.list file from:

```
deb https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r31.5 main
deb https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/t186 r31.5 main
```

to:

```
deb https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r32.7 main
deb https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/t186 r32.7 main
```

and it upgraded my Jetpack to 4.6.1. Unfortunately nvidia does not support Jetpack 5.X.X on TX2 series